# Property gets set to null after segue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, segue

In my prepareForSegue method I'm doing this:

```
LoggedInViewController *view = segue.destinationViewController;

NSLog(@"Preparing for view logged in for user %@ with %d zombies with %@",
          self.context.userName, self.context.zombies.count, view.view);

[view initWithContext:self.context];
```

And in my `initWithContext`-method:

```
- (void)initWithContext:(TestSRConnectionContext *)__context{
    _context = __context;
    NSLog(@"Ok init for user %@ with %d zombies", __context.userName, _context.zombies.count);

}
```

In the log everything is fine.

The view I'm loading is a UITableViewController but no items gets loaded. I have had this table working before so the logic for the table is OK.

So -- the problem I'm having is the _context.zombies is set to null when the view appears; in the viewDidAppear method i check _context.zombies and it is null!

Comment: how are you declaring the property?

Comment: Thank you for your answer tomi2711, I had written the question wrong - context wasn't null but rather context.zombies was. I changed the weak attribute on the property declaration for it to strong and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had written the question wrong - context wasn't null but rather context.zombies was.

I changed the weak attribute on the property declaration for it to strong and now it works.